# Understanding user vs. system stack pointers in Motorola 68k

Tags: assembly, callstack, motorola, 68000, stack-pointer

I'm trying to understand the usage and implementation of a Stacks in assembly language (Motorola 68k).

I know that the MC 68k, has 8 address registers, A7 being the special one. Since it's two stack pointers, sharing the name of "System stack pointer".

And we have two states user state and supervisor state. 
Where:

```
user state- 

certain system resources are blocked and A7 accesses the user stack pointer.
```

`supervisor state-`

```
 all system resources are available and A7 accesses the supervisor stack pointer
```

Now I'm not sure about how to go answering these 2 questions:

Why does the 68000 have two hardware stack pointers?

Write code to

- Save the long-word values of registers D1,D3,A2-A6on the runtimestack.

  ```
  MOVEM D1-D3/A2-A6, -(A7)
  ```

Would this be correct?

Here I'm not sure by what is referred to as "runtimestack", and I'm not sure what the difference of (SP) and (A7) really is. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why does 68000 have two stack pointers? Not sure why, because you could also ask: why does X86 have one stack pointer or why does ARM have 5 stack pointers? SP and A7 are two different names for the same register.

Comment: But how does SP or A7, know which state it's in, when for instance using the MOVEM instruction?

Comment: The processor knows what state it is in currently, so which SP / A7 is the active one depends on the current state.

Comment: Okay so would my MOVEM instruction be correct there? And also, it has two hardware stack pointers to suffice the two states: user and supervisor?

Comment: @rcgldr: x86 has hardware support for using separate user and kernel stacks, though.  This is necessary to protect kernel integrity from multi-threaded programs that could otherwise modify another thread's memory while it was being used by the kernel during a system call or interrupt-handler by the other thread.  Having multiple HW stack regs is just another approach to solving the same problem.  Oh, supercat's answer already said this.

Comment: @PeterCordes - From what I understand, there's only one stack pointer, but for each task, there is a set of 3 values for ESP / RSP in a task state segment (TSS) for ring 2, ring 1, ring 0. These are fixed values (read only in the TSS). The TSS also has space to save all the registers. X86-64 bit mode doesn't have hardware task switch, but it still has TSS.  X86 task switching is more complicated than 68K switching between user / supervisor mode.

Comment: @rcgldr: My point is that x86 still has to solve the same problem that m68k's dual A7 solves.  It's a necessary feature for OS memory protection / priv sep, but there are multiple ways to implement it.  I haven't looked into the details myself, and the actual details of HOW the HW support works for separate stacks for separate priv levels isn't actually important, just that there are ways to do it other than m68k's approach.  Thanks for the summary of the details, though. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, when the 68000 powers on, my understanding is that it basically executes ```MOVE.L 0,SP``` (intentionally did not have the # in front of the zero there.) So what mode is the 68000 in when this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never wrote any 68000 assembler, but from what I can read out of your question this seems to be about user mode vs. supervisor mode. Maybe you should start at the beginning and read the manual?

From the [M68000 FAMILY Programmer’s Reference Manual](http://www.freescale.com/files/archives/doc/ref_manual/M68000PRM.pdf):

1.3.1 Address Register 7 (A7)
In the supervisor programming model register, A7 refers to the interrupt stack pointer, A7’(ISP) and the master stack pointer, A7" (MSP). The supervisor stack pointer is the active stack pointer (ISP or MSP). For processors that do not support ISP or MSP, the system stack is the system stack pointer (SSP). The ISP and MSP are general- purpose address registers for the supervisor mode. They can be used as software stack pointers, index registers, or base address registers. The ISP and MSP can be used for word and long-word operations.

Comment: This certainly aids in my understanding about the stack pointer, but it doesn't answer my other two Questions. (If the code I wrote is correct), and why their is two hardware stack pointers?

Comment: @TTEd - there's no real reason why there are two hardware stack pointers, other than that's how Motorola decided to implement it. The X86 (PC) gets by with one stack pointer, so two stack pointers are a choice, not a necessity.

Comment: So my code for MOVEM certainly compiles (easy68k),mind you I'm not sure if it's doing what the question asks me.

Comment: @rcgldr - There MUST be a reason why there are two, even if it is just because they had a spare one lying on the desk and decided to stick it in.

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland - It's an implementation choice. X86 only has one stack pointer, but for protected mode, one of the control blocks contains a few values to load into the stack pointer if the privilege level changes (like an interrupt).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the additional explanation, I don't like loose ends.

Answer (score 9):

A common requirement for operating systems is that user programs must have a very limited ability to corrupt the overall system.  Many programs need to be able to change the value of their own stack pointer in relatively arbitrary fashion, but any program which can change the stack pointer which is used for handling interrupts could corrupt arbitrary supervisor memory by setting that stack pointer to the address of that memory; the next interrupt would thus trash whatever whatever memory was identified by the stack pointer used for interrupts.  Since user programs should not be able to do that, it's necessary that they not be able to modify the stack pointer used for handling interrupts.

The 68000 handles this issue by having two separate stack-pointer registers, and saying that one will be used when the system is in user mode and the other when it's in supervisor mode.  It's very helpful to have a means by which supervisor-mode code can read or set the stack pointer which was being used in user-mode code, but there's no need for the reverse ability (letting user mode see the supervisor stack), and supervisor-mode code won't generally manipulating the user-mode stack pointer very heavily, so rather than use one of the eight numbered address registers to the user-mode stack pointer, the 68000 requires that all access to it be done via a few special instructions.